# C++ Concatenate attributes of two vectors of different type into new vector

Tags: c++

I have two vectors as follows:

```
std::vector<Foo> v1;
std::vector<Bar> v2;
```

both `Foo` and `Bar` possess the `.baz` attribute, for example of type `int`.

What I would like is to end up with a new vector, combining all `.baz` attributes, in order:

```
std::vector<int> v3;
```

where `v3.size() == v1.size() + v2.size()`

Is there a succinct way of achieving this?

Comment: "in order" In what order? All the `Foo`s and then all the `Bars`, `Bar`s then `Foos`, ascending, descending, or some other ordering that I kind-of need to know more to be able to grasp?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know that you need something more succinct than simply:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> foos = get_foos();
    std::vector<Bar> bars = get_bars();

    std::vector<int> vec;
    auto merge = [](auto const& arg) {return arg.baz;};
    std::transform(foos.begin(), foos.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), merge);
    std::transform(bars.begin(), bars.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), merge);
}
```

Comment: May need a call to `std::sort` in there depending on how the combiniation is to be ordered

Comment: You may `reserve` to appropriate size.

Comment: You may also store the lambda in a variable to reuse it (as you create generic lambda).

Answer (score 2):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it might be:

```
std::vector<int> v3 = ranges::view::concat(ranges::view::transform(v1, &Foo::baz),
                                           ranges::view::transform(v2, &Bar::baz));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcae686d24edf992)

Comment: Nice. In case the OP actually wants to interleave the `baz` values from the two vectors, could range-v3's `interleave_view` be used for this, similarly straight-forward as `concat` above?